# Enable Zend Multibyte Support

Tags: php, iis-7, windows-server-2008

Can someone please give me a little step by step on how to recompile php with zend multibyte support enabled on windows server 2008? OR is there a way to enable it without recompiling? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's only really used for [`declare(encoding)`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.encoding) -- is that why you need it?  Extensions that include multi-byte support like mbstring and Intl do not rely on it.

Comment: I have a WordPress site with the shopp e-commerce plugin installed.I fixed a bunch of things to get the shopp plugin to work on the Windows server but now I'm stuck with this issue: https://shopplugin.net/kb/broken-images-on-windows-server/ which I believe has to do with zend multibyte support.

Comment: Their solution is bogus.  Best practice *forbids* the unicode BOM in PHP scripts, primarily because *most* PHP versions can't see through it.  Even then, the BOM is entirely redundant in UTF-8, which is not byte-order specific.  Your best bet is going to be actively removing the UTF-8 BOM from the scripts, and then telling them to get a clue.  Preferably violently.  With a cluebat.  I'll help.

Comment: Lol "cluebat" that's hilarious...anyways thank you I'll have to look over their scripts tomm. and see if I can remove the UTF-8 BOM and make this stupid plugin work and hopefully will never have to use it again.